# SQLalchemy: refine and chaining subquery with Union

Tags: python, select, sqlalchemy, subquery, union

I would like to construct a query with sqlalchemy, while using the ORM extension. Consider this:

```
class Foo(Base):
    __table__ = 'foo_table'
    id = Column(Integer)
    name = Column(String)
    prop = Column(Integer)
```

now I would like to write a general function, which can return me all Foo's where the name matches some string or where the
prop is some number:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import Query
def match_name(_name):
    return Query(Foo).filter_by(name = _name)

def match_prop(_prop):
    return Query(Foo).filter_by(prop = _prop)
```

Each function should be able to return me an Query, which I can use retrieve ORM objects.
Now considering I am only interested in id and name of these objects, but without altering the functions, I can operate like this:

```
myname = 'foo'
sqry1 = match_name(myname).subquery()
all_name_eq_foo = session.query(sqry1.c.id, sqry1.c.name).all()

myprop = 42
sqry2 = match_prop(myprop).subquery()
all_name_eq_foo = session.query(sqry2.c.id, sqry2.c.name).all()
```

So, now, how to achieve this in one go, while using the superset of results in each subquery, aka
where name matches *OR* prop matches without, *without chaining the filter conditions* 
(the subqueries in this example are just simplified, but might are more complicated for usecase).
 For me this means using *Union*, thus something like this:

```
def match_name_prop(_name, _prop):
    return Query.union([match_name(_name).subquery(), match_prop(_prop).subquery()])
```

with the possibility to later limit the resulting columns:

```
sqry3 = match_name_prop(myname, myprop).subquery()
all_name_eq_foo = session.query(sqry3.c.id, sqry3.c.name).all()
```

But I cannot get this working. Can anybody please help?!

Answer (score 0):

After hours of trying, I think I found an adequate solution:

```
def match_name_prop(_name, _prop):
    return match_name(_name).union(match_prop(_prop))
```

which by itself will return ORM-entities like so:

```
matches = match_name_prop(myname, myprop)
matches.with_session(session).all()
#>>> [<Foo object at 0xFFFFFF>]
```

and then subselecting of desired columns within that entity like so:

```
session.query(Foo.id, Foo.name).select_entity_from(matches.subquery()).all()
#>>> [(42,'foo',)]
```